# Phonegap 3.0 CLI issue in run app for Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

While creating a Phonegap app using the Phonegap command line for the Android platform, I have run in command prompt like below:

```
C:\PhoneGapCL> phonegap create helloworld
C:\PhoneGapCL>  cd helloworld
C:\PhoneGapCL\helloworld>phonegap local run android
```

And I got the following error:

> [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
>      [error] The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android S
>   DK installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your
>    path. Output: 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

Try typing `which android` is if this does show `/path/to/android` then you need to set you path by `PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android/platform-tools:/path/to/android/tools` hope this helps

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand @user1952312 what you are saying about.I have installed latest version of Android Sdk but I couldn't find what is then issue for finding platform for phonegap project compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/myusername/path/to/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/myusername/path/to/android/sdk/tools:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin`

Use the whole absolute path of your folder. Hope it helps.

I'm actually dealing with this error now

```
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY >&/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your PATH is set correctly and you still get this, try this.

Open Android SDK Manager and make sure to fully download latest Android API (for this moment it is API 18), then get all items from Tools and all items from Extras.

This solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with using API 18 of the Android SDK with PhoneGap. Using the Android SDK manager, download and install API 17. That should solve the problem. (Get rid of API 18 if it still doesn't work).